# Rest API request timeout

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, hystrix

I need to timeout my Rest Api when no response is returned. For example, when I make a request and if it takes more than 5 seconds to return a response, then Timeout.

In order to implement this, I opted for Circuit Breaker using Hystrix. But I am not sure whether it is the right way to approach this problem and if it's all good, should Hystrix be configured more?

My current implementation looks like,

Main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableCircuitBreaker
class MyApplication{

}
```

RestController

```
@GetMapping("/data")
@HystrixCommand(commandKey="response")
public String getResponse(){

    Thread.sleep(10000);
    .....
}
```

application.properties

```
hystrix.command.default.execution.isolation.thread.timeoutInMilliseconds=5000
```

When timed out, it throws a HystrixRunTimeException and that's handled with a Custom Exception handler.

Is this the right approach to implement Request Timeout?

Answer (score 1):

You may simply use a native `CompletableFuture` without need to add an external dependency for that:

```
CompletableFuture<String> task = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
    //your code which will return a String response at some point
});
try {
    return task.get(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS); //this will return if the future returns before 5 seconds, else will throw a timeout exception
} catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
    //handle execution issues
} catch (TimeoutException e) {
    //you're called here if you timeout
}
```

The method `CompletableFuture.supplyAsync()` will asynchronously perform the task that makes you retrieve the `String`, hence it should contain your functional code. It should end with a `return <your response>`.

On the other hand, you get the future right after and the method `.get(unit, timeoutUnit)` will synchronously wait for the future to respond by the timeout.

In case of execution error (e.g. an exception is thrown in your functional code), you'll catch it inside the cause of `ExecutionException`.

In case of timeout (meaning the future is not complete by 5 seconds), you will catch a `TimeoutException` and will be able to respond whatever you wish to your caller.

There is also a possibility for `InterruptedException`, coming if the thread asynchronously performing the functional operation gets interrupted. I didn't treat that exception, you'll know better than me how you want to handle it.

Comment: Got it ...thanks. But I have many endpoints and I don't want to touch the existing flow... With Hystrix it's just a few annotations. I am so confused with Hystrix configurations, so I raised this question... Isn't this the right approach?

Comment: @ima.technophyle you can write an utility function which takes the supplier in parameter and does the same for every endpoint. Each endpoint will simply call that generic function and get back the result. Change is not big, but it relies on a known JDK feature instead of an external library. Plus remember, annotations are processed and create code, they will surely end up doing something very similar - just they do it for you.

Comment: ... I Agree... I will try it out anyway... Actually, the code is in production and all are looking for minimal changes to the existing implementation...That's the reason I was going with Hystrix...

Comment: @ima.technophyle I see of course. Hystrix is a powerful library for many things, but for what you need to do, it just means adding an external dependency to production for something that can be easily and "minimally" (maybe not as minimal as the annotation, but still) done using a simple JDK structure :)